# swift overriding method with selector error

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I've recently been learning swift and upon opening a project from a previous beta version I get this error when  trying to compile

```
Overriding method with selector 'initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:' has incompatibe type '(UITableViewCellStyle, String) -> SweetTableViewCell'
```

And here's the line of code giving the error

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    // Initialization code
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `init` method in `UITableViewCell` has been changed a little bit:

```
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
                                                         ^
```

the `reuseIdentifier` is now an optional string.

Answer (score 1):

Apple makes many arguments and method values optional in new XCode versions. In your case the second argument - `reuseIdentifier` - should be `String?` not `String`.